# KDB+: How to Update a Value from Table with Another Value of Different Type

Tags: types, kdb

The `meta` of the table `relevantOverrides` is as follows:

```
security j
startDate d
endDate d
dataItem s
val f
```

I have an update query:

```
 relevantOverrides:update val:163390j from relevantOverrides where security = 18767
```

The val column has a float type, but I need to insert the updated value as an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the list is of an atomic type, a number of a different type cannot be added in place easily.

One way of doing what you want is to append the generic null (::) or a value of the type you want to update (in this case a long) which will turn your list into a mixed list.

You can then update the values at the indices specified by the where clause before removing the generic null from the list and updating.

```
q)t
security startDate  endDate    dataItem val
-------------------------------------------------
2        2011.11.15 2003.11.17 dol      2.310108
8        2015.03.27 2015.01.12 nca      0.8724017
6        2012.06.15 2015.05.03 dfp      1.024432
9        2012.04.15 2001.07.18 hon      8.671096
0        2000.09.02 2009.12.29 ofm      7.278528

q)update val:-1_ @[val,(::);where security=6;:;163390j] from t
security startDate  endDate    dataItem val
------------------------------------------------
2        2011.11.15 2003.11.17 dol      2.310108
8        2015.03.27 2015.01.12 nca      163390
6        2012.06.15 2015.05.03 dfp      1.024432
9        2012.04.15 2001.07.18 hon      8.671096
0        2000.09.02 2009.12.29 ofm      7.278528
```

Although it is possible, you may run into difficulties when it comes operating on the table:

- Firstly you will not be able to save the resultant table to disk as
  anything other than a flat table without running into issues
- If you are able to get around this, you will have a lower query
  performance due to the column not being a vector.
- The update function itself will be expensive as the column needs
  to be ammended.